# Confused as to the Difference between the Sum of Conditional Probabilities and the Sum of Intersections

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

When completing practice problems for Bayes Theorem, I came across this question:

> A diagnostic test has a probability 0.95 of giving a positive result
>   when applied to a person suffering from a certain disease, and a
>   probability 0.10 of giving a (false) positive when applied to a
>   non-sufferer. It is estimated that 0.5 % of the population are
>   sufferers. Suppose that the test is now administered to a person about
>   whom we have no relevant information relating to the disease (apart
>   from the fact that he/she comes from this population).
>
> Calculate the probability that the test result will be positive

The solution was:

> If ***T*** = Test positive and ***S = Sufferer***, then ***P(T) =
>   P(T|S)P(S) + P(T|S')P(S')***

While this answer makes sense to me, I thought that the answer would be ***P(T) = P(T|S) + P(T|S')***, as this way you would also get ***P(T)*** for all patients, those who are suffering and those who are not.

I can't understand the difference between ***P(T) = P(T|S)P(S) + P(T|S')P(S')*** and my answer, ***P(T) = P(T|S) + P(T|S')***

Comment: Well, you do get all the patients in the correct answer, but you take a weighted sum.  Think about what the answer would be with your method if the test never gave a false negative.  You'd have $P(T|S)=1$ and when you added, you'd get a probability greater than $1$!

Comment: You can think of conditional probability $P(T | S)$ as the probability of $T$ happening when you restrict the probability space $\Omega$ to $\Omega_S$ where $S$ happens. What this intuition tells us is that it makes no sense to add two conditional probabilities $P(X|S_1)$ and $P(Y|S_2)$ where $S_1\neq S_2$.

Comment: You can also try: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between $P(T \cap S)$ and $P(T| S) = \frac{P(T \cap S)}{P(S)}$.

We have \begin{align} 
P(T) &= P(T \cap S) + P(T \cap S') \\
&= \frac{P(T\cap S)}{P(S)}\cdot P(S) + \frac{P(T\cap S')}{P(S')}\cdot P(S')\\
&=P(T|S)P(S) + P(T|S')P(S')
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is, I understand the mathematical reasoning behind it, but I have trouble understanding the difference at an intuitive level.

Comment: You have a fair coin, the probability of getting a tail ($T$) is $0.5$. You decide to either go to the singing class ($S$) or go to the gym ($S'$), exactly $1$ of such event can happen. You decide to toss the coin at art class or the gym. Will the probability of getting a tail become $0.5+0.5=1$ just because there are two possible outcome? It doesn't, the thing is $T|S$ and $T|S'$ are events from different universe. In one of the universe, you go the singing class, in another parallel universe, you go the gym. We can't just add the probability across different universe.

Comment: That clarifies it for me. Thanks!